# when i run kubectl cluster-info display services is forbidden

Tags: kubectl

I'm receiving the following error for `kubectl cluster-info` :

```
To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
Error from server (Forbidden): services is forbidden: User "admin" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"
```

Comment: would be good if you could add the following info:

* did it work before?
* what does `kubectl get clusterrolebinding cluster-admin -o yaml` say? Is user a member of `system:masters` group ?
* what is the output of `kubectl auth can-i list services` ?
* what is the output of `kubectl auth can-i --list --namespace=kube-system` ?

I suspect that the user is not a member of system:masters

Comment: so, what was the problem exactly and what has been done to mitigate it. Appreciate if you can post the solution as an answer, so next user will find resolve the same issue faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can check permissions in the GCP Console under IAM -> Members -> click on the right the `Over granted permissions` tab and it will display a list of permissions. Look out for services.list permissions.